# React, AWS GraphQL error handling - JSON response

Tags: json, reactjs, error-handling, graphql

I'm seeing this response in the webconsole logs on receipt of a graphQL mutation api call. This is fine because I'm expecting the error and trying to handle it.

Does this mean "0" is a key here? and if it is, `response.0.errorType` is invalid syntax.

```
    "0": {
        "errorType": "DynamoDB:ConditionalCheckFailedException",
        "errorInfo": null,
        "locations": [
            {
                "line": 2,
                "column": 3,
                "sourceName": null
            }
        ],
        "message": "The conditional request failed (Service: DynamoDb, Status Code: 400, Request ID: BUEAM6ACKQBPHKDHGNASM49C4BVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG, Extended Request ID: null)"
    }
}
```

Is there a correct syntax to retrieve the "error.Type" value? Thanks for any help, in advance.

Comment: If object property start with a digit, it should be call object["0"], or object[0], see https://javascript.info/object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the key has quotes around it, it's a string (`"0"`) instead of a number (`0`). Your original syntax would only work if the array key were a number.

```js
console.log("0" === 0) // "false"
```

In order to access that key, supply the correct string as your array key:

```js
error['0'].errorType
```